# Reinforcement Learning: what does "γ-just" mean in advantage function estimation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In "HIGH-DIMENSIONAL CONTINUOUS CONTROL USING GENERALIZED ADVANTAGE ESTIMATION" by Schulman et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438) the advantage estimator, under certain conditions, is claimed to be "γ-just", where γ is the discount factor.
What does it mean?
Thanks

EDIT:
If i interpreted correctly the Definition 1 in the mentioned paper, it means that an estimator is γ-just if it is an exact estimator of the discounted version of A. Is it correct? This being said, I still don't understand the subscripts of the estimator At. Why did the authors write 0:∞ ? The estimate (as well as the real value of A) should depend only on the trajectory to go. What am I missing?

Comment: Because this notion is clearly stated in your reference at Definition 1, please explain to us what kind of answer you are looking for here that would add anything to that definition.

Comment: Try to make the question self-evident by including relevant information from the paper in the question. In the contrary case, the reader is forced to look up exactly what is being referred to in the paper itself, and, being that the material is somewhat obscure, not many readers are likely to feel inclined to do so.